# How do I traverse a LinkedHashMap in order ({atrivial, isAsked == true}];

Tags: java

How does one do an inorder traversal of this Java LinkedHashMap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String key: map.________)
  fields.add(key);
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what kind of order? Do you want to sort the keys alphabetically, and then traverse, or in the order they were inserted?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a loop: simply call

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
```

Comment: nice<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 1):

`map.keySet()` is probably what you're looking for.

From the docs of [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the
>   order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So **YES**, it does maintain the order of insertion, even after you enter a **MILLION** keys.

Comment: That is usually sorted for a HashMap, but is it guaranteed to be in order by insertion for millions of keys?